# Trigger to detect whether DELETE or UPDATE is called by stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a scenario where certain users must have the rights to update or delete certain records in production.  What I want to do put in a safeguard to make sure they do not accidentally update or delete a large section (or entirety) of the table, but only a few records as per their need.  So I wrote a simple trigger to accomplish this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_check
ON dbo.My_table
AFTER UPDATE,DELETE AS  
BEGIN 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted) > 15
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Bulk deletes from this table are not allowed', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END  
END --end trigger
```

But here is the problem. There is a stored procedure that can do bulk updates to the table.  The users can and should be allowed to call the stored procedure, as it's scope is more constrained.  So my trigger would unfortunately preclude them from calling the stored proc when they need to.

The only solution I have thought of is to run the stored proc as an impersonated user, then modify the trigger to exclude that user from the logic. But that will bring up other issues in my environment.  Not unsurmountable, but annoying. Nevertheless, this seems the only viable option.

Am I thinking about this the right way, or is there a better approach?

Comment: Perhaps save a `SESSION_CONTEXT` then read it back in the trigger. By the way, you shouldn't `RAISERROR/ROLLBACK` in a trigger, instead just `THROW` and the rollback will happen automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check of `@@NESTLEVEL` in the trigger. The value will be 1 for an ad-hoc statement or 2 when called from the stored procedure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_check
ON dbo.My_table
AFTER UPDATE,DELETE AS  
BEGIN 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted) > 15
        AND @@NESTLEVEL = 1 --ad-hoc delete
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Bulk deletes from this table are not allowed', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END;  
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually handle this with [`CONTEXT_INFO()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This gives you a better control than `@@NESTLEVEL` because you can actually identify the specific stored procedure doing the calling and handle them individually if required. You do this as follows:

1. Add the procedure name to `CONTEXT_INFO()` e.g.

```
  -- START OF STORED PROCEDURE
  -- Tell the trigger who we are, and that we can be trusted.
  declare @OldContext char(128), @NewContext varbinary(128);

  -- Get existing context_info()
  set @OldContext = coalesce(convert(char(128), context_info()), '');
  -- Add new info to context_info
  set @NewContext = convert(varbinary(128),convert(char(128), 'dbo.MyProcedureName'));
  -- Store new context info
  set context_info @NewContext;


  -- STORED PROCEDURE CONTENT


  -- END OF STORED PROCEDURE
  -- Restore context_info
  set @NewContext = convert(varbinary(128), @OldContext);
  set context_info @NewContext;
```

2. In the trigger return early if the `CONTEXT_INFO()` is from a trusted source e.g.

```
-- START OF TRIGGER
declare @NewContext char(128) = coalesce(convert(char(128),context_info()),'');

if @NewContext in ('dbo.MyProcedureName') begin
  return;
end;
```

Another advantage of this approach (for other trigger uses) is you can avoid carrying out logic in a trigger when called from a SP. Because often you put logic in a trigger to ensure that it happens regardless of how the insert/update/delete happens. But when done in an SP you can ensure the required logic is carried out within the SP which avoids the need to do it in a trigger. Especially useful if you end up with performance issues due to too much logic in the trigger.

Note: For SQL Server 2016+ you can use [`SESSION_CONTEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be:

- Create a stored procedure to perform the desired work
- If the criteria varies greatly, create several procedures for each "kind" of work
- Grant EXECUTE permissions to the desired users on those procedures ("kind of work") that they are permitted to do. (You are using Database Roles and Domain Groups, right?)
- Revoke permissions to make ad hoc data modifications on the table

It can be fussy to set up, but it supports the "Principle of Least Permissions", permitting users to do only what they are supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I am using roles for everything, so users are appropriate grouped into what they can and cannot do.  However, the number of ad hoc tasks that can be performed is large enough that creating a stored proc for every "kind" of work would be cumbersome.  But that would be another reasonable approach.